# Why don't f-strings change when variables they reference change?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.6, f-string

While playing with new f-strings in the recent Python 3.6 release, I've noticed the following:

1. We create a `foo` variable with value `bar`:

   ```
   >>> foo = 'bar'
   ```
2. Then, we declare a new variable, which is our f-string, and it should take `foo` to be formatted:

   ```
   >>> baz = f'Hanging on in {foo}'
   ```
3. Ok, all going fine and then we call `baz` to check its value:

   ```
   >>> baz
   'Hanging on in bar'
   ```
4. Let's try to change the value of `foo` and call `baz` again:

   ```
   >>> foo = 'spam'
   >>> baz
   'Hanging on in bar'
   ```

Shouldn't it be dynamic? Why does this happen? I thought the f-string would update if the value of `foo` changed, but this didn't happened. I don't understand how this works.

Comment: How would you expect the expression `'Hanging on in ' + foo` to behave?

Comment: Or `'hanging on in {}'.format(foo)` - they **don't** keep a reference to the interpolated value.

Comment: As far as I understand, these fancy 'f-strings' are just some sort of syntactic sugar for `str.format`.

Comment: @JoshLee A better question is how they expect `foo = f'{foo}'` to behave.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The `f-string` has *already* been evaluated when you executed:

```
>>> baz = f'Hanging on in {foo}'
```

Specifically, it looked up the value for the name `foo` and replaced it with `'bar'`, the value that was found for it. `baz` then contains the string after it has been formatted.

`f-string`s aren't constant; meaning, they don't have a replacement field inside them waiting for evaluation *after* being evaluated. *They evaluate when you execute them*, after that, the assigned value is *just a normal string*:

```
>>> type(f'hanging on in {foo}')
<class 'str'>
```

For reference, see [the section on *Formatted String Literals*](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#formatted-string-literals):

> [..] While other string literals always have a constant value, formatted strings are really *expressions evaluated at run time*. [..]

After the expression (the look-up for the replacement field and its consequent formatting) is performed, there's nothing special about them, the expression has been evaluated to a string and assigned to `baz`.

Comment: What is `baz` after creation?  A regular string?  Or does it have some special `f` attributes?

Comment: @hpaulj `type(baz)` will tell you; ordinary string.

Answer (score 1):

Strings are immutable and once a string is created, it can no longer be changed.

`foo` and more importantly `baz` are both strings. That means when you create them they go into memory and can no longer be changed.

Once you assigned `foo = bar` you created this object and assigned it to a specific location in memory. Same thing was done with `baz`.

Even though `baz` was as a [Format string literal](https://docs.python.org/3.6/reference/lexical_analysis.html#f-strings) does not mean that it is no longer immutable since:

```
In [4]: type(baz)
Out[4]: str
```

By doing so, `baz` was created as an object and assigned to your memory as `Hanging on in bar`, thus its relation to `foo` is purely during instantiation. During which `baz` seeks the object `foo` and concatenate it where appropriate.

Once you created `foo = 'spam'` you **destroyed** the original assignment of `foo` and create a new one in memory.