# Resolving a variable dynamically in python

Tags: python, f-string, dynamic-variables

Say I have a string -

`my_str = "From {country} with Love"`

Variable `country` is not available at the moment and is set at a later stage to

`country = "Russia"`.

Now
Can I print string with the inline variable value dynamically resolved. Something like -

`print(f"{my_str}")`

which will output

`From Russia with Love`

I tried to use eval() but didn't help.

Comment: ``my_str = f"From {country} with Love"`` ??

Comment: Is that what you mean: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42497625/how-to-postpone-defer-the-evaluation-of-f-strings

Comment: actually no, u have to say `my_str = f"From {country} with Love"` then u can proceed as said in the Q and the output will be fine

Answer (score 6):

```
my_str = "From {} with Love"
country = "Russia"
print(my_str.format(country))
```

If you like to work with names you can also do:

```
my_str = "From {country} with Love"
country = "Russia"
print(my_str.format(country=country))
```

Comment: this is the correct answer.

Comment: why not use `f` strings, there is no harm, except for compatiblity with python 2.x

Comment: Thanks @Andreas, exactly what I was looking for. Didn't know that we can use it based on names as well.

Comment: @NEO Glad I could help, happy coding!

Comment: @Cool Cloud An f-string is syntax I don't think you will be able to generate syntax through a string.

Comment: hmmm? what to do you mean?

Comment: Look at the answer of  Eugene Anufriev, he asked the same and found a post with a good explaination.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using Templating for example [Pythons built in templating](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#template-strings):

```
from string import Template

t = Template("From $country with Love")
s = t.substitute(country="Russia")
print(s)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create the variable like this:

```py
my_str = f"From {country} with Love"
```

Then when the `country` variable gets assigned it will be replaced automatically in the `my_str` variable.

Comment: Note that this will raise an NameError when you try to print the string without initiating the variable `country`.

Comment: Correct @DjerroNeth, I get the error ```NameError: name 'country' is not defined```.
@pacuna I don't have the variable set while assigning my_str. It becomes available at a later stage.

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
variable = "Russia"
print(f'my country is {variable} and I live in it')
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work too:

```
country = "Russia"
my_str = f"From {country} with Love"
print(f"{my_str}")
```

Comment: For f-string you have to initialize "country" before the string. also you then could simply do: print(my_str)

Comment: Thanks, good point. Btw, can f-strings be used for a variable definition like in the example I've posted above?

Comment: I don't think so because as far as I am aware f strings are syntax not objects. And are most likely not be able to manipulate sytax through a string.

Comment: heh, I think I found the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41306928/why-dont-f-strings-change-when-variables-they-reference-change

Comment: ah, good explaination, far better then I could do :P

Answer (score 0):

Here's an idea:

```
def str(country):
  my_str="From %s with Love" %country
  print(my_str)
str("Russia")
```

This will print `From Russia with Love`.